Wordpress additional update of publications after importing WP All Import Pro
I ran into a problem updating records after importing WP All Import Pro. In general, when I do the import, the records are saved, everything is OK. I have fields created via CMB2. In one of these fields, I am passing a serialized array of data to Google Map to display the location on the map on the page of this entry.
If you go to the record page after importing, then this map is not visible. But if you go to edit the record and click update, the map appears. Can you tell me where to dig?

My gut instinct is this has something to do with the serialization of the data: something might be unserializing it when you don't want it to, or not unserializing it when you want it to. You'll need to check with the plugins' various support streams about this, though; third-party plugin support is off topic here.
